# Transferring ownership of .NET mutexes

Tags: .net, windows-services, ipc, mutex, signals

I've read about `mutex`'s being owned by threads and only usable by the owning thread. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747055/how-to-use-named-mutex-and-shared-memory-between-a-windows-service-and-a-process/3747345#3747345) the solution suggests that each process must take ownership of the mutex before signalling the other that is is through. I must admit my stupidity here, I don't know how I would use events for IPC as they haven't popped up in my reading of MSDN, I like the uniquely named `mutex`'s as my solution but I don't even know how to transfer ownership between the WindowsService and regular process. Please help.

Can I add, Jon Skeet's tutorial [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/waithandles.shtml) informs me that to communicate between different users, as I suppose `LocalSystem` to be,  requires prefixing `mutex` names with 'Global\'. I could not find any mention of this in the .NET documentation, I suppose he is right and must I look outside of the MSDN system more than I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take ownership on already existing Mutex you can use static method [Mutex.OpenExisting()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz3w40d4.aspx) with MutexRights = TakeOwnership

```
public static Mutex OpenExisting(
                                string name,    
                                MutexRights rights)
```

- The rights parameter must include the MutexRights.Synchronize flag to allow threads to wait on the mutex and the MutexRights.Modify flag to allow them to call the [ReleaseMutex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex.aspx) method.
- The OpenExisting method attempts to open an existing named mutex. If the system mutex does not exist, this method throws an exception instead of creating the system object.

Considering that OpenExisting() can throw [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx) exception I would suggest to create a new Mutex using following constructor:

```
public Mutex(
    bool initiallyOwned,
    string name,
    out bool createdNew
)
```

and then by analyzing a value of the `createdNew` variable you can check whether mutext already exists or new one was created.

Comment: Almost like you read the page I linked in my answer (before I could) while I was reading gmamaladze's code! I won't tire of hearing it said again though. What confuses me is will both the first and second caller own the same named mutex? As in both would have to release it before either could lock it? This would seem to violate my goal of having just one lock on it at a time.

Comment: @John: so if you aware of this technique what is the question?

Comment: Well, I can't retype the intelli-sense parameter description of `initiallyOwned` but I gather if it is false, or the named mutex already exists then the mutex returned would be a reference to one already owned. But that begs the question, "What if I supply false and it is not already owned", I would then have a reference to an unowned mutex. I think that's right.

Comment: @John : sorry for confusing. Regarding link you've provided - I've not read it, it was enough to look at the Mutex class members in the MSDN

Answer (score 0):

First process:

```
// Create a new Mutex. 
// True means this thread/process has inital ownership
Mutex mut = new Mutex(true, "some unique name");
//Now do your job
//Release ownership
mut.ReleaseMutex();
```

Now the code for second process.

```
// Create an instance of mutex object with the same name
// This means this thread/process has NOT inital ownership
Mutex mut = Mutex.OpenExisting("some unique name");
//Your thread will block until the first passes ownership
mut.WaitOne();
//Now you have it and can do your job
```

Comment: Good example. They are not 1st and 2nd to me but equal. In VS, the intelli-sense tells me that the first parameter applies _if_ the mutex is created as a result of the call. So if what you term the '1st' went second it could not assume it has ownership. That's just how I read it.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-389016.html) page seems to have answered my question fairly completely, here's a taste:

> Well, after a successful `mutex.WaitOne()` has completed the current thread is the owner of mutex. Then after a call to `mutex.ReleaseMutex()` the thread does not own the mutex any more.